# How to save a copy of web page DOM using selenium webdriver and JAVA/C#

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, c#, chrome

I need to write a crawler that crawls throughout exercises available on my website (1200 exercises) and save a copy of DOM in my local as I have to use that DOM to create an exercise DVD. Can anyone please suggest a way to do it?

Please see the screenshot to get more clear understanding.
[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with testing?

Comment: I'm using selenium webdriver to write a crawler that's it.. and trying to figure out if there is any way to do it using java/C# or any inbuilt method in selenium.

Comment: I would look into tools like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) it's a highly effective HTML parser

Answer (score 2):

You can try to dump page source and parse it, or dump only element source.

Page source to pageSource variable (Java):

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

Element source to elementSource variable (Java):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
String elementSource = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```